# How to overcome performance decrease with simple class containing only one POD member compared to plain POD type?

Tags: c++, performance, templates, visual-c++, c++17

I don't really know if the origin of the problem has actually something to do with POD types, but at least I can see the difference there. What I would like to achieve is that my template `Pod` class behaves like a simple builtin type (e.g. float) in regards of performance.

So what I currently have is a templated class with a tag and value type:

```
template<typename TTag, typename TValue>
class Pod
{
public:
    Pod() = default;
    Pod( TValue value ) : m_value{ value } {};

    TValue& value() noexcept
    {
        return m_value;
    }

    TValue const& value() const noexcept
    {
        return m_value;
    }

    Pod& operator+=( Pod const& src ) noexcept
    {
        m_value += src.m_value;
        return *this;
    }

    Pod& operator*=( TValue const& src ) noexcept
    {
        m_value *= src;
        return *this;
    }

private:
    TValue m_value{};
};

template<typename TTag, typename TValue>
Pod<TTag, TValue>
        operator+( Pod<TTag, TValue> lhs, Pod<TTag, TValue> const& rhs ) noexcept
{
    lhs += rhs;
    return lhs;
}

template<typename TTag, typename TValue>
Pod<TTag, TValue> operator*( Pod<TTag, TValue> lhs, TValue const& rhs ) noexcept
{
    lhs *= rhs;
    return lhs;
}
```

Now lets take a simple test operation like: (A)

```
std::vector<Pod<A_tag, float>> lhs( size );
std::vector<Pod<A_tag, float>> rhs( size );
std::vector<Pod<A_tag, float>> res( size );

for ( std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i )
{
    res[ i ] = lhs[ i ] + rhs[ i ];
}
```

and compare it to: (B)

```
std::vector<float> lhs( size );
std::vector<float> rhs( size );
std::vector<float> res( size );

for ( std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i )
{
    res[ i ] = lhs[ i ] + rhs[ i ];
}
```

What I noticed with my `googlebenchmark` test cases, is that (B) is around 3 times faster than (A).
If I change (A) to: (C)

```
std::vector<Pod<A_tag, float>> lhs( size );
std::vector<Pod<A_tag, float>> rhs( size );
std::vector<Pod<A_tag, float>> res( size );

auto plhs = &( lhs[ 0 ].value() );
auto prhs = &( rhs[ 0 ].value() );
for ( std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i )
{
    res[ i ].value() = plhs[ i ] + prhs[ i ];
}
```

I can achieve similar performance for (C) like (B).

There are now two question that came up to my mind:

1. Is variant (C) legal regarding standard or is it actually UB or something similar.
2. Is there any way to define the template class `Pod` that it behaves similar to the underlying value type in regards of performance.

I can use C++17, if that helps. I tested everything with Visual Studio 2019 **Release** mode /O2.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Your constructor results in requiring a pro-forma extra copy (`value` gets passed by value). Perhaps your compiler is not smart enough to optimize the extra copy away. Same problem with your `operator+` and `operator*` overloads, on top of the pro-forma default construction. I think that reimplementing the constructor, and the operator overloads to give the compiler and extra nudge in the right direction will result in a very high likelyhood of the resulting code being identical to the native code. Or, perhaps your compiler is smart enough but you did not turn on optimizations?

Comment: of course I tested release ;-) I use cmake to create build project with standard settings, so release has O2 (max speed) optimization as compile option.

Answer (score 1):

> *Is variant (C) legal regarding standard or is it actually UB or something similar.*

Variant (C) is technically UB - a strict aliasing violation for any `i` >= 1. You're iterating over a pointer to `float` residing inside `Pod` as-if it was in an array by itself. But `Pod<...>` and `float` are incompatible types.

In addition it's not portable - it may be OK in VC++, but technically there can be padding at the end of `Pod`, so it's not guaranteed that the `float`s will be arranged with no gaps between them.

> Is there any way to define the template class `Pod` that it behaves similar to the underlying value type in regards of performance.

Yes, you can disable auto-vectorization in the first version, then all versions will perform similarly :)

```
#pragma loop( no_vector )
```

Basically MSVC is able to auto-vectorize only very simple loops currently. We can see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/1ET5Enxhj) that it auto-vectorized the first version (if we can call it that):

```
$LL25@Baseline:
        movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [rax+r9*4]
        addss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [r10+r9*4]
        movss   DWORD PTR [rdx+r9*4], xmm0
        movss   xmm1, DWORD PTR [r10+r9*4+4]
        addss   xmm1, DWORD PTR [rax+r9*4+4]
        movss   DWORD PTR [rdx+r9*4+4], xmm1
        movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [rax+r9*4+8]
        addss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [r10+r9*4+8]
        movss   DWORD PTR [rdx+r9*4+8], xmm0
        movss   xmm1, DWORD PTR [rax+r9*4+12]
        addss   xmm1, DWORD PTR [r10+r9*4+12]
        movss   DWORD PTR [rdx+r9*4+12], xmm1
        add     r9, 4
        cmp     r9, 9997                      ; 0000270dH
        jb      SHORT $LL25@Baseline
        cmp     r9, 10000               ; 00002710H
        jae     $LN23@Baseline
```

But is just going nuts around the `Pod` version, unfortunately:

```
$LL4@PodVec:
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdx]
        movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [r9+rax-12]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rcx]
        addss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [r9+rax-12]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [r8]
        movss   DWORD PTR [r9+rax-12], xmm0
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdx]
        movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [r9+rax-8]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rcx]
        addss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [r9+rax-8]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [r8]
        movss   DWORD PTR [r9+rax-8], xmm0
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdx]
        movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [r9+rax-4]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rcx]
        addss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [r9+rax-4]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [r8]
        movss   DWORD PTR [r9+rax-4], xmm0
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdx]
        movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [r9+rax]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rcx]
        addss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [r9+rax]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [r8]
        movss   DWORD PTR [r9+rax], xmm0
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdx]
        movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [r9+rax+4]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rcx]
        addss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [r9+rax+4]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [r8]
        movss   DWORD PTR [r9+rax+4], xmm0
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdx]
        movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [r9+rax+8]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rcx]
        addss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [r9+rax+8]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [r8]
        movss   DWORD PTR [r9+rax+8], xmm0
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdx]
        movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [r9+rax+12]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rcx]
        addss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [r9+rax+12]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [r8]
        movss   DWORD PTR [r9+rax+12], xmm0
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdx]
        movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [r9+rax+16]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rcx]
        addss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [r9+rax+16]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [r8]
        movss   DWORD PTR [r9+rax+16], xmm0
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdx]
        movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [r9+rax+20]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rcx]
        addss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [r9+rax+20]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [r8]
        movss   DWORD PTR [r9+rax+20], xmm0
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdx]
        movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [r9+rax+24]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rcx]
        addss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [r9+rax+24]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [r8]
        movss   DWORD PTR [r9+rax+24], xmm0
        add     r9, 40                                    ; 00000028H
        cmp     r9, 40012               ; 00009c4cH
        jb      $LL4@PodVec
```

I tried to help it out in various *legal* ways by simplifying the code to make it maximally easy to optimize:

```
#include <vector>
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>

template<typename TValue>
struct Pod {
public:
    Pod() noexcept {}
    Pod(TValue value) noexcept : m_value{ value } {}

    Pod operator+ (Pod src) const noexcept {
        return m_value + src.m_value;
    }

private:
    TValue m_value{};
};

constexpr std::size_t size = 10000;

inline void Baseline(std::vector<float>& lhs, std::vector<float>& rhs, std::vector<float>& res) {
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        res[i] = lhs[i] + rhs[i];
    }
}

inline void PodVec(std::vector<Pod<float>>& lhs, std::vector<Pod<float>>& rhs, std::vector<Pod<float>>& res) {
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        res[i] = lhs[i] + rhs[i];
    }
}

inline void PodPtr(Pod<float>* lhs, Pod<float>* rhs, Pod<float>* res) {
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        res[i] = lhs[i] + rhs[i];
    }
}

using Iter = std::vector<Pod<float>>::iterator;

inline void PodIter(Iter lhs, Iter rhs, Iter res, Iter endres) {
    for (; res != endres; lhs++, rhs++, res++)
    {
        *res = *lhs + *rhs;
    }
}

void BaselineTest(benchmark::State& state) {
    std::vector<float> lhs(size), rhs(size), res(size);
    for (auto _ : state) {
        Baseline(lhs, rhs, res);
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(res);
    }
}
BENCHMARK(BaselineTest);

void PodVecTest(benchmark::State& state) {
    std::vector<Pod<float>> lhs(size), rhs(size), res(size);
    for (auto _ : state) {
        PodVec(lhs, rhs, res);
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(res);
    }
}
BENCHMARK(PodVecTest);

void PodPtrTest(benchmark::State& state) {
    std::vector<Pod<float>> lhs(size), rhs(size), res(size);
    for (auto _ : state) {
        PodPtr(&lhs[0], &rhs[0], &res[0]);
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(res);
    }
}
BENCHMARK(PodPtrTest);

void PodIterTest(benchmark::State& state) {
    std::vector<Pod<float>> lhs(size), rhs(size), res(size);
    for (auto _ : state) {
        PodIter(begin(lhs), begin(rhs), begin(res), end(res));
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(res);
    }
}
BENCHMARK(PodIterTest);
```

But no luck, unfortunately (curiously though, every version performs differently):

```
-------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark             Time             CPU   Iterations
-------------------------------------------------------
BaselineTest       1824 ns         1842 ns       373333
PodVecTest         6166 ns         6278 ns       112000
PodPtrTest         5185 ns         5162 ns       112000
PodIterTest        4663 ns         4604 ns       149333
```

At the same time, GCC 10 has no problem with either version:

```
----------------------------------------------------
Benchmark             Time           CPU Iterations
----------------------------------------------------
BaselineTest       1469 ns       1469 ns     422409
PodVecTest         1464 ns       1464 ns     484971
PodPtrTest         1424 ns       1424 ns     491200
PodIterTest        1420 ns       1420 ns     495973
```

And this is how the GCC loop assembly looks like:

```
.L6:
        movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [rcx+rax*4]
        addss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [rsi+rax*4]
        movss   DWORD PTR [rdx+rax*4], xmm0
        add     rax, 1
        cmp     rax, 10000
        jne     .L6
```

Interestingly, Clang 11 is having a bit of difficulty with the `vector<Pod>` version, too ([link](https://quick-bench.com/q/DvlwwY9w8vG_mdMUfW_hEAQyqLo)), which was unexpected.

The moral of the story: [there are no zero-cost abstractions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rHIkrotSwcc). In this example if you want to benefit from vectorization, I see no way other than to use "raw" `vector<float>`s (or switch to GCC).

Comment: Thx for your answer and the effort you put into analyzing all the stuff, that gave me some valuable insights. So basically it is possible to be optimized by compiler (GCC) but I have to wait until Visual Studio supports this as well ...